# JavaBean class rules

Tags: java, javabeans

What are the correct rules to write a JavaBean class?

I'm confused because some books use MUST while other user SHOULD or COULD to describe
the writing rule:

i.e.

- a bean class MUST implements Serializable or SHOULD?
- the instance variables MUST be private or SHOULD BE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A JavaBean is defined by its *properties* (i.e. its getter and setter methods), not it's *fields*. Although the terms are used interchangably, that is actually not correct. The [`Introspector`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) mechanism ignores fields completely.

**Example**

Take this (awfully designed) Javabean:

```
public class TestBean {
    private int baz;
    private char[] phleem;

    public String getFoo() {
        return new String(phleem);
    }
    public void setFoo(final String foo) {
        this.phleem = foo.toCharArray();
    }
    public long getBar() {
        return baz;
    }
    public void setBar(final long bar) {
        this.baz = (int) bar;
    }
}
```

You'd think the properties are:

- "baz" (`int`)
- "phleem" (`char[]`)

but now let's inspect it with the Javabeans introspector:

```
for (PropertyDescriptor descriptor : Introspector
        .getBeanInfo(TestBean.class, Object.class)
        .getPropertyDescriptors()) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + descriptor.getName() + 
                     ", type: " + descriptor.getPropertyType());
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Name: bar, type: long
Name: foo, type: class java.lang.String
```

**Conclusion:**

Getters and setters are what define a Javabeans property. It's a *convention* that they are backed by fields of the same name and type, but the fields are not actually part of the Javabean properties (although many documentations will suggest otherwise).

---

On re-reading my answer: it is meant as an addendum to the other answers. If you want a short and simple answer, go with skaffman's.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand well. If there is not a mandatory match between a variable name and a get/set method name how can a builder tool get or set that variable given i.e. its name?

Comment: @xdevel2000: Because that "mismatch" is defined by the javaBean spec, as a naming convention.

Comment: As I said: it's a convention, nothing more. In 99% of the cases you should use this convention, and tools will help you *only* if you use this convention. But I just wanted to make you aware that the underlying fields *are not* bean properties, while the getter and setter methods are.

Comment: This is not really relevant (and an old answer), but why do you mention terribly designed?

Comment: @sdasdadas it's not that terrible, it's just misleading

Answer (score 2):

- It is a public class.
- It has a public parameterless constructor (though it may have other constructors 
  as well)
- It implements Serializable interface (i.e. it can be made persistent, so its state can 
  be saved)
- It has properties with  “getter” and “setter” methods named by following 
  JavaBeans naming patterns
- It has events which follow the standard Java event model with the registration 
  methods named by following the JavaBeans naming patterns
- It may have other methods which do not follow the naming patterns. These 
  methods are not exposed by a builder tool.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous poster - [skaffman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21234/skaffman). It is always a good practice to override, `toString()`, `hashCode()`, `equals()` and finally write a overloaded constructor that has all the fields (that this class has) as input.

Be sure not to use other references (like List, HashMaps etc) in the `toString()` and `hashCode()`'s implementation.

On a side note, eclipse has built-in functionality to generate them for you..

Answer (score 1):

A Java Bean is a Java class that should follow the following conventions:

- It should have a no-arg constructor.
- It should be `Serializable`.
- It should provide methods to set and get the values of the properties, known as `getter` and `setter` methods.

Answer (score 0):

All the above and it should not cross the boundaries of Java API . It means it should not extend or implement any classes or interface,but one relaxation is there it can implement only one serializable interfce why because it is a marker interface